# Can I make a local module with the Swift Package manager?

Tags: swift, build, swift-package-manager

I know the Swift package manager can compile code from github as a module for my project, but can I tell the package manager to compile code that is stored locally on my computer instead?

The idea is I have some code that I want to separate off from the rest of my project, so I keep it in a folder and the Swift compiler will build it so that that code can be imported like any other module.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can reference a local directory in your `Package.swift` file, but it must be a Git repository. Also, initializing the repo, committing, and tagging is not sufficient; the repository must be pushed to a remote for `swift build` to function correctly.

According to the [SwiftPM Usage Guide](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md):

> Packages are Git repositories, tagged with semantic versions, containing a Package.swift file at their root. Initializing the package created a Package.swift file, but to make it a usable package we need to initialize a Git repository with at least one version tag.

The [Swift Package Manager Documentation](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#dependencies) also states that "you can specify a URL (or local path) to any valid Swift package" and provides an example `Package.swift` with a local file reference: `.Package(url: "../StringExtensions", "1.0.0")`.

*Note*: I edited the answer to clarify that Swift Package Manager can reference a local path, but the path **must** contain a valid Git repository with a tag. My original test project pointed to a dependent local path that contained a `.git` directory, and so it successfully built with `swift build`.

Comment: didn’t work. I got `error: Directory at path ... is not a Git repository`. You probably left a stray `.git` folder in yours which is why the package manager took it as a git repo

Comment: Perhaps it's implicit above, but for changes to the Package/repo, the tag/version apparently must be updated for the version to become available, locally. E.g., if it was 1.0.0 before your change, you have to update the tag to 1.0.1. At least this has been my experience so far. (BTW, I hope this behavior changes in the future. This seems really clunky for purely local development.)

Answer (score 20):

You can also use

```
.package(path: "path to folder")
```

if you don't want the overhead of an additional git repo. This can even be a relative path.

Comment: This worked very well, the package folder doesn't need to be a git repo.

Comment: This looks like a great solution, @rounak! Especially if it means that the product that includes the package automatically checks the package location when it compiles and looks for an update. Is it available in Xcode 12.5? In which case where is the .package(path: "path to folder") directive placed?

Answer (score 15):

With the Swift 4 version tools, there's different means to do this-- where you don't have to provide a tagged version:

```
.package(url: "<path to repo>", .branch("master")),
```

See also: https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/PackageDescriptionV4.md

Comment: I see one caveat on this: You have to at least commit your change to your branch to have it visible to what you are compiling. It seems you have to do a `swift package update` too.